# How to stop a running command in this case?

Tags: rust, terminal

This the following code runs a command, outputs each line in real-time, then handles the success or failure:

```
use std::{
    io::{BufRead, BufReader, Write},
    process::{Command, Stdio},
};

pub struct CmdRunner {
    pub command: std::process::Command,
}

impl CmdRunner {
    pub fn new(command_string: &str, input: Option<&str>) -> CmdRunner {
        let mut command = Command::new("script");

        command.arg("-qec");

        if let Some(input_str) = input {
            command.arg(command_string.replace("{}", input_str));
        } else {
            command.arg(command_string);
        }

        command.arg("/dev/null");

        CmdRunner { command }
    }

    pub fn run(&mut self, stdout: &mut impl Write) {
        self.command.stdout(Stdio::piped());
        self.command.stderr(Stdio::piped());

        let mut child = self.command.spawn().expect("failed to spawn command");
        let stdout_pipe = child.stdout.take().unwrap();
        let stdout_reader = BufReader::new(stdout_pipe);
        let stderr_pipe = child.stderr.take().unwrap();
        let stderr_reader = BufReader::new(stderr_pipe);

        let stdout_thread = std::thread::spawn(move || {
            for line in stdout_reader.lines() {
                if let Ok(line) = line {
                    print!("{}\r\n", line);
                }
            }
        });

        let stderr_thread = std::thread::spawn(move || {
            for line in stderr_reader.lines() {
                if let Ok(line) = line {
                    print!("{}\r\n", line);
                }
            }
        });

        let status = child.wait().expect("failed to wait for command");

        stdout_thread.join().expect("failed to join stdout thread");
        stderr_thread.join().expect("failed to join stderr thread");

        if status.success() {
            write!(stdout, "Command executed successfully\r\n").unwrap();
        } else {
            write!(
                stdout,
                "Command failed with exit code {}\r\n",
                status.code().unwrap_or(-1)
            )
            .unwrap();
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut cmd_runner = CmdRunner::new("sleep 10 && echo test", None);
    let mut stdout = Vec::new();

    cmd_runner.run(&mut stdout);
    println!("stdout: {:?}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&stdout).to_string());
}
```

It works. But when a command is running, I can't stop it, even when I press Ctrl + C repeatedly.

Why is this, and how to make Ctrl + C stop the execution of the command?

Note: If I run `sleep 10 && echo test` directly in the terminal, the command will halt if I press Ctrl + C.

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=165219fb1642bdd605d78bc092d609a5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parent process has to shut down its children, or they'll become zombies (reattached to pid 1, the parent's parent process). [Documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/process/struct.Child.html):

> There is no implementation of Drop for child processes, so if you do not ensure the Child has exited then it will continue to run, even after the Child handle to the child process has gone out of scope.
>
> Calling [wait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/process/struct.Child.html#method.wait) (or other functions that wrap around it) will make the parent process wait until the child has actually exited before continuing.

Also, you may register a [signal handler](https://rust-cli.github.io/book/in-depth/signals.html#differences-between-operating-systems).

Comment: A SIGINT handler might be more relevant as Ctrl + C will send that, not SIGKILL.

Comment: So I should listen to Ctrl + C in `main()` with this: `ctrlc::set_handler(move || {println!("received Ctrl+C!"); })`, but instead of using `println!`, I should exit the process?

Comment: Yeah. The other way around would be implementation of Drop trait for the wrapped Child type.